# Ubuntu 12.04: apt-get can't parse repository url if username contains @ ('at' sign)

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, repository

I added a repository URL that contains to '@' (at sign) to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myrepo.list

```
deb https://FOO@BAR:PASS@domain.com/xyz precise non-free
```

apt-get update fails with:

```
Couldn't resolve host 'BAR:PASS@domain.com'
```

I tried to escape '@' using %40, and \ (backslash), but to no effect: the error message is the same. 
Apt version:

```
$ apt-get --version
apt 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.26 for amd64 compiled on Aug  5 2015 19:06:57
```

Is there a way to add the repository on Ubuntu 12.04? The URL is parsed correctly on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If it parses correctly on 14.04, file a bug report asking for the fix to be backported.